# What are the different CLR handle types?

Tags: .net, debugging, clr

I've been watching Mario Hewardt's Pluralsight course on [*.NET Internals and Advanced Debugging Techniques*](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/dotnet-internals-adv-debug) and I've come across the concept of handles in the CLR.

Now I've already found this [awesome SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704029/what-is-the-difference-between-a-pointer-and-a-handle) about what a handle *is*, however Mario refers to the handle types:

- Strong Handle
- Pinned Handle
- Async Pinned Handle ([SO description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554927/what-is-an-async-pinned-handle))
- Ref Count Handle
- Weak Long Handle
- Weak Short Handle
- Other Handle

Which aren't really explained in the video and I assume are expected knowledge for those taking this course.

I did a Google and couldn't really find a satisfactory description of what these are, so I was hoping an SO user could help me out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found this in my notes for windbg:

- #ESP    - ESP=Extended Stack Pointer, Object is in use on a stack (attention, !gcroot may return false positives here, read !help gcroot in windbg)
- #DOMAIN(x):HANDLE(Strong) - Strong reference, Typically a static variable
- #DOMAIN(x):HANDLE(WeakLn) - Weak Long Handle, A weak reference that is tracked through finalization (can be resurrected)
- #DOMAIN(x):HANDLE(WeakSh) - Weak Short Handle, A weak reference, can't be resurrected
- #DOMAIN(x):HANDLE(Pinned) - Pinned object, pinned at a specific address, can't move around during garbage collection.
- #DOMAIN(x):HANDLE(RefCnt) - Reference count, referenced as long as the reference count is > 0.

I've taken it long time ago from some MSDN blog I believe, it could have been [Tess'](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/), but I can't trace it exactly at the moment. (BTW, if you're into .net debugging and you don't know it yet and want to use windbg/sos/sosex, this is the place to learn).

Alejandro Campos Magencio has also [a fine series of articles](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2009/07/07/managed-debugging-with-windbg-introduction-and-index.aspx) on debugging with windbg and sos; in [part 3](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2009/08/17/managed-debugging-with-windbg-managed-heap-part-3.aspx) you can find there some confirmations of definitions of most of GC Handle types.